# what eigen originally means in English or Latin?

Tags: meaning, etymology

In mathematics, there is a very important concept of Eigen-decomposition.

I think I understand this concept reasonably well. However, I don't understand why it is called "eigen", rather than other names.

My question is, what does Eigen originally mean?

Can you give me a clue?

Thanks

Comment: There's a discussion of the origin of the term on Wikipedia Talk: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3AEigenvector

Answer (score 1):

Eigen (adj)= means own, in Dutch(Nederlands) and German(Deutsch).

(http://www.etymologiebank.nl/trefwoord/eigen )

The Anglo-Saxon version is:
Ægan to own, v. agan.(Anglo-Saxon Dictionary. 1838.)(personal property)

Why it is called Eigen:
".....all other standard types of matrix decomposition use the term "decomposition" in their names, e.g., Cholesky decomposition, Hessenberg decomposition, and so on. As a result, the decomposition of a matrix into matrices composed of its eigenvectors and eigenvalues is called eigen" decomposition in this work.
( http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EigenDecomposition.html )